# How to concatenate based on number of duplicates - MS Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

Is there a way to concatenate multiple columns if the a row is duplicate? I have a spreadsheet where column A has duplicate team but there area and LD  (column b and c) are different value. I would like to have a formulate at column E where it will concatenate column B and C with dash and append next row values. See the attached picture highlighted row E. Any idea how to do this with excel formula or may be VBA.  I tried this formula in column E =IF(A3=A4,D3&";"&D4) but it returns false for the last duplicate row.

[image]

Comment: `...concatenate column B and C with dash and append next row values.` Every value in your column E seems to follow this description, with the exception of `E4` and `E8`. What is the rule for these two cells?

Comment: I added Column D and did a concatenate. Column is just a if formula with concatenate but and it's not working the way i wanted to work. Row 2 and Row 3 for column E should be empty and Row 3 for column E should be concatenated value since Team 400 duplicates 3 times. and same goes for team 660

Comment: Will the teams (column A) be sorted ascending as in the image?

Comment: I can sort it by column A if it's better for formula

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible with formulas. It requires a VBA-based solution.

I wrote a custom routine for you. Please place this in a standard code module:

```
Public Sub ConcatTeamZones()
    Const SOURCE = "A1"
    Const OUTPUT = "E1"
    Dim i&, j&, s$, v, w
    v = Range(SOURCE).CurrentRegion
    ReDim w(1 To UBound(v), 0)
    For i = 2 To UBound(w)
        If v(i, 1) <> v(i - 1, 1) Then
            w(i - 1, 0) = s
            s = s & v(i, 2) & "-" & v(i, 3)
            s = ""
        Else
            s = s & ";"
        End If
        s = s & v(i, 2) & "-" & v(i, 3)
    Next
    w(i - 1, 0) = s
    Range(OUTPUT).Resize(UBound(w)) = w
End Sub
```

And then from the worksheet with your team data, press ALT-F8 to bring up the Macro Dialog. Run the ConcatTeamZones macro.

Note 1: this assumes that column A is sorted.

Note 2: You can edit the first two lines to specify which columns contains the source (team data) and which column you wish the output.

Comment: Let me test this . Thank you mr. hero. and I will let you know in few

Comment: Genius: Worked in first try. OMG. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done using formulas, *it’s just a matter of perspective*:

*Assuming data is sorted by Team*

This formula gives the concatenated result with the maximum of combinations on top. Enter this formula in cell `E2` and copy till last record.

```
=CONCATENATE($D2,IF(EXACT($A2,$A3),";"&$E3,""))
```

To assign the max possible combinations to each Team enter this formula in `F2` and copy till last record.

```
=INDEX($E:$E,MATCH($A2,$A:$A,0),0)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would do it...

Cell "A1": =COUNTIF(B$2:B2,B2)&B2   - This is to create a unique key. Copy down the length of your table

Then I would use an advanced query (with vba maybe) to create a list of unique values for team in the "F" column

Cell "G2": =VLOOKUP("1"&F2,A:D,3,0)&"-"&VLOOKUP("1"&F2,A:D,4,0)&IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP("2"&F2,A:D,3,0)),"",",  "&VLOOKUP("2"&F2,A:D,3,0)&"-"&VLOOKUP("2"&F2,A:D,4,0))&IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP("3"&F2,A:D,3,0)),"",",  "&VLOOKUP("3"&F2,A:D,3,0)&"-"&VLOOKUP("3"&F2,A:D,4,0))&IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP("4"&F2,A:D,3,0)),"",",  "&VLOOKUP("4"&F2,A:D,3,0)&"-"&VLOOKUP("4"&F2,A:D,4,0))

This function creates your combined references. It would be longer if you expected more than 4 occurrences of teams.

Just copy "IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP("4"&F2,A:D,3,0)),"",",  "&VLOOKUP("4"&F2,A:D,3,0)&"-"&VLOOKUP("4"&F2,A:D,4,0))" and change the "4" to "5" etc

You could hide column A (to tidy up).

Sorry, I tried to include an image but insufficient reputation :-)